# how to recall onCreate by button onclicklistener android?

Tags: android

I need to know how to recall onCreate by button onclicklistener android as reload page?

I mean, there is a button in my page and I want to reload this main page once I click on this button.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not recommended.

1. All the stuff that you do in onCreate should be put in a separate method.
2. onCreate should be as light as possible.
3. With onClick you should call this method that does whatever you want.

Calling onCreate repeatedly with keep on increasing your activity stack and hit the performance hard.